# Using PIVOT to Expand Arrays into Columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested, pivot

I have a fairly compact dataset which is great for everything except it seems using AutoML to train, so I need to unnest the data in order to be able to run the ML Training on it.

My Data is laid out as 4 columns, the first 3 are each an array of 6 elements:

[image]

Or in JSON:

```json
{
 "vRMSMin":[245.484,245.571,245.477,245.505,245.47,245.557],
 "vRMSMax":[246.63,246.583,246.662,246.601,246.599,246.455],
 "eReactiveNegativeKwh":[0.0179,0.0086,0.0142,0.0024,0.0188,0.0097],
 "timestamp": "1629861271"
}
```

I have tried using UNNEST and CROSS JOIN for these but the query wont finish likely due to the huge number of output columns I will have and the amount of data, so I was looking at using PIVOT but cant find enough documentation on how to use it to get the desired result of:

```
vRMSMin_0,vRMSMin_1,vRMSMin_2,vRMSMin_3,vRMSMin_4,vRMSMin_5,vRMSMax_0,vRMSMax_1,vRMSMax_2,vRMSMax_3,vRMSMax_4,vRMSMax_5,....etc
```

**Please note** - this is not the same question as creating a PIVOT table (therefore not a duplicate of all of the other answers around for it that I have searched), I am specifically asking how I can use the PIVOT function on an array to generate columns rather than using rows to create other columns.

I got somewhere around here before my brain melted:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT vRMSMin, vRMSMax
    FROM mydata.data
)
PIVOT
(
    MIN( (SELECT SUM(x) FROM UNNEST(vRMSMin) x))
    FOR vRMSMin[offset()] in (0,1,2,3,4,5)
)
```

I am mostly struggling as to how to get the column names and the values, could be that I am asking too much of BigQuery and should look to handle this separately in the client but this would mean double imports, would prefer to be able to handle this via ELT if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach as an example (easy to be extended with as many extra columns as you need)

```
with `mydata.data` as (
  select 1 id, [245.484,245.571,245.477,245.505,245.47,245.557] as vRMSMin,
    [246.63,246.583,246.662,246.601,246.599,246.455] vRMSMax union all 
  select 2, [145.484,145.571,145.477,145.505,145.47,145.557] ,
    [146.63,146.583,146.662,146.601,146.599,146.455] 

)
select * 
from (
  select id, a, b, offset
  from `mydata.data`, 
  unnest(vRMSMin) a with offset
  join unnest(vRMSMax) b with offset
  using (offset)
)
pivot (min(a) as vRMSMin, min(b) as vRMSMax for offset in (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

with output

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider voting up if not yet :o)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use anything but array indexing for this?

```
select timestamp,
       vRMSMin[Ordinal(1)], vRMSMin[Ordinal(2)], vRMSMin[Ordinal(3)], vRMSMin[Ordinal(4)], vRMSMin[Ordinal(5)], vRMSMin[Ordinal(6)],
       vRMSMax[Ordinal(1)], vRMSMax[Ordinal(2)], vRMSMax[Ordinal(3)], vRMSMax[Ordinal(4)], vRMSMax[Ordinal(5)], vRMSMax[Ordinal(6)],
       eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(1)], eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(2)], eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(3)], eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(4)], eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(5)], eReactiveNegativeKwh[Ordinal(6)]
from mydata.data;
```

Each row can be processed independently, so this should be the fastest way to do what you want.

Comment: The number of fields I have in the array is prohibitive and each time a new datapoint comes in it would be another 6-12 items per line, this was my fallback method but PIVOT produces a much cleaner and modifiable query, especially if across the board the number of data points are different (as they often are), this way I can template the same query and just change the offset range.

Comment: @Voycey . . . I don't really see how pivot or another method would actually be simpler than just directly accessing the array elements.  This would certainly be the fastest method.

Comment: Because it comes down to the tooling that generates this query - it adds much more complexity to that part to do via indexing.